# How to connect a template that generates Flask-Security to view

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-security

I am writing a site for Flask, I have connected Flask-Security and I have a completely different template generated on the user authorization page, can it be connected to routes and how?
Here is the code for the view:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login_page():
    form = AuthorizationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
        if email and username and password:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)

            return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
        else:
            flash('Неправильний логін або пароль')
    else:
        flash('Будь ласка,завповніть всі поля')
return render_template('templates/security/login_user.html', title='Авторизація',
                       form=form, css_link=css_file)
```

But there is no effect
Help me please

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of unpack here!
First - you have defined a new form (is it derived from the flask-security LoginForm?); a new template, and a new view - and the view has the same URL as the default Flask-Security /login - not sure which one will take precedence.
Your code example actually has the 'render_template' outside the view code - a cut-n-paste error?

In Flask-Security you can independently override the template (still using the default Login form) or extend the Form (and do your validation in your form::validate method). It should be rare that you have to build your own view.